# If $\sum^\infty_n a_n$ is convergent, then is $\sum^\infty_n\sqrt{a_n}$ also convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_n a_n$ be a convergent series, where $a_n>0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it true that $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_n\sqrt{a_n}$ is also convergent?

My first thought was to use a comparison test: We know that for $a_n\geq 1$. But this seems wrong to me since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ implies that for big enough $n$, $a_n<1$ (which causes the test to fail).

I have a feeling that this is not a true statement. I just can't come up with any counter examples.

Comment: It is the other way around. If $\,\sum_n |a_n|\,$ is convergent then $\,\sum_n|a_n|^2\,$ is convergent also.

Answer (score 7):

No. Take

$$a_n =\frac{1}{n^2}$$ for which $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

is **convergent***.
Of course
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$ **diverges** as it is a harmonic series.

*Convergence can be shown by computing partial sums $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{k} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{k-1}{k}$$ as $$\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$ for $n>1$ and then taking limit: $$\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=2}^{k} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \frac{k-1}{k}=1$$